# sp_rename stops working after 2nd rename of list of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a script to rename tables that I copied into another database. However, when I run it it gives me an error saying that the renamed table is in use. this is the 2nd table that it renamed.
Error message "Error: The new name 'IPro_ALERT_1604220600' is already in use as a object name and would cause a duplicate that is not permitted."

I am not sure why it is giving this error and I have looked around this site and elsewhere and I think my code should work. Any ideas on what/why it is doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Code for renaming tables:

```
USE [II_to_IIRP]
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
    DECLARE @table_part SYSNAME

    DECLARE comp_cursor cursor FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND TABLE_NAME  LIKE '%_1604220600'  
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

OPEN COMP_CURSOR

    FETCH NEXT FROM COMP_CURSOR INTO @table_name
    SET @table_part = 'IPro_' + @table_name 
    WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0 and @@error = 0 )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Changing table Name '+@table_name
    EXEC sp_rename @table_name, @table_part
    PRINT 'Done Changing table '+@table_name
    SELECT 'drop table dbo.'+@table_name where @table_name <> @table_part
    FETCH NEXT FROM COMP_CURSOR INTO @table_name
    PRINT 'Getting next table ' + @table_name
END
CLOSE COMP_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE COMP_CURSOR
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're modifying the data that cursor are reading. Try to insert the data from your cursor in a temporary table and then use this table as your cursor.

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
    DECLARE @table_part SYSNAME

     SELECT TABLE_NAME 
     INTO #TEMPTABLES
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND TABLE_NAME  LIKE '%_1604220600'  
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

    DECLARE comp_cursor cursor FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM #TEMPTABLES
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it still errors out same way. It gets next table from list but doesnt release object of first table rename.

Comment: you could use FOR UPDATE OF clause in cursor, it could work in your first code, like this: 
DECLARE comp_cursor cursor FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES FOR UPDATE OF TABLE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually quite clear. You are trying to rename your table to the name that already exists.
You forgot to include:

```
SET @table_part = 'IPro_' + @table_name
```

inside your cursor loop, so you are renaming the next table with the same name as the previous one.

Comment: So I should have it this way -

Comment: @vbnewbie, did my answer work? Is something unclear?

Comment: I moved the set below the While and it just keeps running. after  20 minutes i stopped it. Did i move the Set condition to the right spot?

Comment: Yes, it is in the right place (just after `BEGIN` part of the `WHILE`). You also need to follow @Ricardo Pontual advice and create a temporary table / table variable

Comment: RE "after 20 minutes i stopped it": Your script has a lot of PRINT commands, so you should have sme idea what the script was doing or it was doing anything at all.